# Convergence of a type of Monte Carlo integration which is different from the common one

Tags: probability, integration, monte-carlo, quantile-function

$a_i \in (0,1)$, $I = 1,\cdots,N$ are $N$ random samples from uniform distribution $U(0,1)$. $a_i$ is in ascending order $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_N$.

$Q(p)$, $p\in(0,1)$ is a differentiable quantile function of random variable $X$.

The Monte Carlo integration gives the mean and variance by $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N Q(a_i)$ and $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N Q(a_i)^2$.

Now suppose there is another set of random samples $b_i \in (0,1)$, $I = 1,\cdots,N$ in ascending order from uniform distribution.

$\bf Question:$ do we have
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N Q(a_i)Q(b_i) \rightarrow \text{Var(X)} \,\,?
$$
Further, do we have asymptotic normality $
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N Q(a_i)Q(b_i) \rightarrow N(\text{Var(X)},D)?
$ How do we find the variance $D$?

---

I tried plugging in Taylor's Theorem $Q(a_i) = Q(b_i) + (b_i - a_i)Q'(b_i) + \frac{1}{2}(b_i - a_i)^2 Q''(b_i) + o(|(b_i - a_i)^2|)$, but couldn't proceed. I am considering fixing $a_i = \frac{i}{N+1}$ for simplicity.

Comment: Are $(a_k)_{k \in\ \mathbb{N}},(b_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ all IID $\sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes, they are iid.

Comment: What do you mean by 'ordered'? Would 'indexed by $1,2,...,N$' convey the same meaning?

Comment: What you end up is averaging the product of two independent copies of the same distribution, which ends up yielding the product of the means instead of the expected value of the square. In symbols $E[XY]=E[X] E[Y]=\mu^2$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with $E[X]=E[Y]=\mu$.

Comment: @Snoop It means that $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_N$.

Comment: @Ian $a_i$, $b_i$ are in ascending order. Does it still hold? At least when $a_i = b_i =  \frac{i}{N+1}$, it is not $\mu^2$.

Comment: Oh, if they're both sorted then that changes things, whereas sorting them in the previous cases didn't do anything.